# New user posts comment as answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, not-an-answer

What should I do in the First Posts, Late Answers and Low Quality Post review queues when I see that a new user has posted a comment as an answer (they don't have enough rep to post comments yet)?

Comment: In *which* review queue?  They're all radically different in how they handle different situations.

Comment: You just flag it as _"Not an answer"_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That depends on what queue you're in.  For example, if you're in LQP that's very much the wrong thing to be doing.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Because I didn't specify which queue? Arun was able to provide a perfect answer to what I think is a reasonable question

Comment: @reggaeguitar He just guessed.  He could just as easily have guessed wrong.  His answer is either incorrect or incomplete for most of the other queues out there.  If your question was actually clear as to what you were asking about, that wouldn't be the case.

Comment: Downvoting and voting to close my question about how to be a better reviewer just makes me want to not review at all, I don't understand why everyone has to be so high and mighty on this site, it's very offputting. I searched for another question to answer mine and nothing came up, I'm sure this will be helpful for people in the future as evidenced by the 9 upvotes to Arun's answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the First Posts and Late Answers queue, **Flag it as not an answer** ( and also leave a comment telling them the reasons in a nice way ).

In the Low Quality Posts queue, Recommend Deletion as "a comment posted as an answer"

Even if they are new users, they should only provide answers in Answers. We must keep Stack Overflow clean with Quality answers. Letting them post comments as answers would only encourage future readers to do the same

Comment: Although I agree that this is probably the best way of doing it, this will still be a problem as long as comments can't be either accepted or upgraded to answers. I fear that many correct comments (that do answer to question) gets overlooked since there was no accepted answer.

Comment: @DanielLarsson, rather than just posting a low quality answer that would have been better of as an answer, it would be best to add a much more detailed answer for future reference. If a comment answers the question, then it can be explained to make it suitable as an answer as well ( typo's and other small problems are exceptions, those questions should be closed instead ). So, better to post an answer with a good explanation rather than post a small comment which may be overlooked.